# SVOD and Social capabilities

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I represent a leading online music tuition platform. We are considering using Craft to develop our new platform. We have a couple of questions about the capabilities of the platform.

1 - Can we build an [SVOD and TVOD](https://imagenevp.com/video-on-demand/) platform on Craft? The video would be pulled from our CDN and displayed via JW player.

2 - Can we build a social side to our site, where members can share content to a centralized social dashboard.

Any help or advice would be greatly received.

Answer (score 1):

I built a website very similar to what you're describing using ExpressionEngine years ago. It's definitely doable in Craft, and it'd be much easier than most other platforms I can think of.

However, as Brad noted in his reply, it will take some development effort.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of some broad questions, but given enough time, talent and money, you can build virtually anything you want in Craft. :)

The front-end of a Craft site is 100% up to you, so you can use whatever video player you want pulling from whatever sources you want.

Commerce doesn't have native [subscription support](https://craftcms.uservoice.com/forums/295386-commerce/suggestions/7814868-subscriptions), yet, but it is high on the to-do list.  You can use an existing plugin like [Charge](https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/charge), which supports Stripe subscriptions, or you can roll your own [custom plugin](https://pluginsfactori.io) that has its own business logic.

Both Craft and Commerce have tons of [hooks](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference) and [events](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference) allowing you to [extend](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/extendability) functionality.

Craft has support for [users, users groups and permissions](https://craftcms.com/docs/users) so you can setup your templates and plugins to allow them to share and decide who gets access to them.

So, yes... doable, but it will take some not-insignificant development effort.